# Django - How do I solve the problem of adding members?

Tags: django

I'm using [django-groups-manager](https://github.com/vittoriozamboni/django-groups-manager).

There is a member section. I get an error while recording. I'm missing or making mistakes. Where could it be?

> TypeError at /accounts/register/
>
> Member() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

**views.py**

```
from groups_manager.models import Group, GroupType, Member

def register_view(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        new_group_name = form.cleaned_data['new_group_name']
        new_group, created = Group.objects.update_or_create(name=new_group_name)
        user.groups.add(AGroup.objects.get(name=new_group_name))
        member = form.cleaned_data['member']
        member = Member.objects.create(name=member)
        user.save()
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'accounts/form.html', {'form': form, 'title': 'Üye Ol'})
```

***This line problematic:***

```
member = Member.objects.create(name=member)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `first_name`, there is no `name` parameter in Member model

```
member = Member.objects.create(first_name = member)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So how do I add this member to the group?

Comment: @witcher Accept this answer if it was useful. Formulate and create new detailed question.